# Is there a way in C to have the compiler/linker give an error if a function is not defined?

Tags: c, plugins, shared-libraries

In my case I am writing a simple plugin system in C using dlfcn.h (linux). The plugins are compiled separately from the main program and result in a bunch of .so files.

There are certain functions that must be defined in the plugin in order for the the plugin to be called properly by the main program. Ideally I would like each plugin to have included in it a .h file or something that somehow states what functions a valid plugin must have, if these functions are not defined in the plugin I would like the plugin to fail compilation.

Comment: You may use `nm` to parse the object files and observe if the required functions are defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after doing some research and asking a few people that I know of on IRC I have found the following solution:

Since I am using gcc I am able to use a linker script.

linker.script:

```
ASSERT(DEFINED(funcA), "must define funcA" ) ;
ASSERT(DEFINED(funcB), "must define funcB" ) ;
```

If either of those functions are not defined, then a custom error message will be output when the program tries to link.

(more info on linker script syntax can be found here: http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html)

When compiling simply add the linker script file after the source file:

```
gcc -o test main.c linker.script
```

Another possibility:

Something that I didn't think of (seems a bit obvious now) that was brought to my attention is you can create small program that loads your plugin and checks to see that you have valid function pointers to all of the functions that you want your plugin to have. Then incorporate this into your build system, be it a makefile or a script or whatever. This has the benefit that you are no longer limited to using a particular compiler to make this work. As well as you can do some more sophisticated checks for other other things. The only downside being you have a little more work to do to get it set up.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can enforce that a function be defined at compile time. However, if you use gcc toolchain, you can use the `--undefined` flag when linking to enforce that a symbol be defined.

```
ld --undefined foo
```

will treat `foo` as though it is an undefined symbol that must be defined for the linker to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.

It's common practice, to only define two exported functions in a library opened by `dlopen()`, one to import functions in your plugin and one to export functions of your plugin.

A few lines of code are better than any explanation:

```
struct plugin_import {
    void (*draw)(float);
    void (*update)(float);
};
struct plugin_export {
    int (*get_version)(void);
    void (*set_version)(int);
};

extern void import(struct plugin_import *);
extern void export(struct plugin_export *);

int setup(void)
{
    struct plugin_export out = {0};
    struct plugin_import in;

    /* give the plugin our function pointers */
    in.draw = &draw, in.update = &update;
    import(&in);

    /* get our functions out of the plugin */
    export(&out);

    /* verify that all functions are defined */
    if (out.get_version == NULL || out.set_version == NULL)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

This is very similar to the system Quake 2 used. You can look at the source [here](https://github.com/id-Software/Quake-2/blob/372afde46e7defc9dd2d719a1732b8ace1fa096e/client/ref.h#L131).

 With the only difference, Quake 2 only exported a single function, which im- and exports the functions defined by the dynamic library at once.

Comment: Would you mind expanding your explanation a bit? I don't quite understand what your code example is showing. (for example I don't know what the import and export functions are doing) I also don't know if this code is suppose to be in the plugin or the main program. In other words what is the goal here? (I ask because I may be thinking differently about how to structure a plugin system, or maybe not, I am unsure)

Comment: @LongBoolean If I understood you correctly, you have a program which loads dynamic libraries at runtime (plugins, in your case), and your question was if it's possible to give you a compiler error if a function is not defined, am I right?

Comment: Correct, When the plugin is compiled I would like some kind of error. (I do not want an error when compiling the main program, thus me saying that compiling the main program and the plugins is separate from each other) I suppose a linker error would also be acceptable if there is no way to accomplish this task at compile time.